# What's the difference between type and data type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm a little confused as to the difference between a ***type*** and a ***data type*** in Haskell.

From the literature I have encountered I got the impression they were different concepts.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

*Type* and *data type* refer to exactly the same concept.

The Haskell keywords `type` and `data` are different, though: `data` allows you to introduce a new algebraic data type, while `type` just makes a type synonym.

See the [Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Type) for details.

Comment: To complete the picture, there is `newtype` too. Grasping the difference between `newtype T a = T a` and `data T a = T a` is difficult, but quite important.

Comment: i saw that newtype on an example. So what is the difference in your example?

Comment: @user997112 `newtype` is just a compile-time type used to create a sort of synonym, but treated as a different type. You could wrap it inside a `data`, but it would add some overhead at run-time. `newtype` makes it explicit to the compiler that you want the type differentiation, without the run-time overhead. For the long story: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Newtype

Answer (score 6):

The terms are sometimes mixed, but usually a "data type" refers to a type introduced using the `data` keyword, which has constructors you can pattern match on. These are also called algebraic data types".

Just "type" is a more general term which also includes types created using `newtype`, function types and so on.

Comment: So would type on its own include Integer etc?