# Define a data type to represent a nested list of strings

Tags: haskell

I am just starting out learning haskell and I find myself challenged trying to define a data type to represented a list of lists of `String`'s. That sounds a little confusing but this is essentially what a data type of this form would look like:

```
[["abc", "def", "ghi"], ["abc", "def", "ghi"], ["abc", "def", "ghi"]]
```

Each of the inner lists will always have a length of 3, but the strings inside can be of arbitrary length greater than one.

I tried this:

```
data MyType = Lists [String] | List [MyType]
```

But I'm not sure if its correct, or maybe that I don't know how to use it. If it is correct, how would I go about constructing a list of lists of these words, or if it is incorrect, what would be the correct way of defining this type?

Comment: The type you want is just `[(String, String, String)]`.

Comment: Good answers already.  Also consider `[[String]]`, which may be more convenient if you treat the three inner strings uniformly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the inner lists will always have a length of 3

The data structure you're looking for is tuple. Its fundamental difference from list is that tuple's type depends on the number of elements in it. You can read about it [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out)

It's going to look like:

```
[("abc", "def", "ghi"), ("abc", "def", "ghi"), ("abc", "def", "ghi")]
```

The type of this structure is `[(String, String, String)]`

Therefore, `MyType` will be something like:

```
data MyType = Lists (String, String, String) | List [MyType]
```

Comment: How can I use a type like this? For example if I cons a list like this `"abc":"def":"ghi":[]`, how can I construct a new `MyType` with this list as the first entry?

Comment: For example, `("abc", "def", "ghi") : []` gives `[("abc", "def", "ghi")]`. To construct `MyType`, simply `Lists ("a", "b", "c")`

Answer (score 2):

You only need to define the type, data is used for other purpouses:

```
type MyType = [(String, String, String)]
```

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7916394/1695172)
If you really want to create a new Algebraic data type, for example:

```
data MyType = Tup3 String String String | List [MyType] deriving Show
```

[Live example](https://repl.it/KZ1v/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a type of lists whose elements are "three element lists", then you can just use a list of triples (tuples of three elements).

`type MyType = [(String, String, String)]`

For example, `[]`, `[("a","b","c")]` or `[("abc", "def", "ghi"), ("abc", "def", "ghi"), ("abc", "def", "ghi")]` are inhabitants of `MyType`.

Comment aside: As other anwers stated, if the lenght of the lists is fixed, then it's not a list what you are talking about, it's rather a vector or tuple.